# Javascript Variables Issue

Tags: javascript, variables

Hello I am trying to get this program to add ALL of the total costs that accumulate throughout this loop. But the program keeps printing the most recent cost rather than all of the products  that have been "purchased". Here is my code: `

```
        var Customer_Name, Discount, Product="", Price, Quantity="", Cost ;
        var blanket_price = 25;
        var lotion_price = 60;
        var surfboard_price = 60;
        var sunscreen_price = 60;
        var Customer_Name = prompt("Welcome to Jersey Shore Inc.! What is your name?","Type Name Here");
        alert("Hello "+Customer_Name+", Please look through all available products and services before placing your order.");


    do
    {


    Product= prompt("What product would you like?","Type Product Name Here");
    Quantity= prompt("How much of the "+Product+" would you like?","Type Quantity Here");
    var Total_Cost;
    var SumOrderTotal=0;

         if (Product == "blanket")
            {
                alert("You received a 50% discount! Click okay to see your receipt below.");
                Total_Cost= 0.5*(Quantity*blanket_price);
                Cost=(Quantity*blanket_price);
                Discount = .50*blanket_price;
            }
            else if (Product == "lotion")
            {
                alert("You received a 50% discount! Click okay to see your receipt below.");
                Total_Cost= 0.5*(Quantity*lotion_price);
                Cost=(Quantity*lotion_price);
                Discount = .50*lotion_price;
            }
            else if (Product == "surfboard")
            {
                alert("You received a 50% discount!Click okay to see your receipt below.");
                Total_Cost= 0.5*(Quantity*surfboard_price);
                Cost=(Quantity*surfboard_price);
                Discount = .50*surfboard_price;

            }
            else if (Product == "sunscreen")
            {
                alert("You received a 50% discount! Click okay to see your receipt below.");
                Total_Cost= 0.5*(Quantity*sunscreen_price);
                Cost=(Quantity*sunscreen_price);
                Discount = .50*sunscreen_price;

            }

             if((Product=="blanket" || Product=="sunscreen" || Product=="lotion" || Product=="surfboard"))
            {

                document.write("The cost of buying " + Quantity+ " of " + Product + " is $ "+ Cost +". </br>");
                document.write("The discount for this purchase is $ "+Total_Cost+". <br/>");



            }
            else 
            {
                alert("Sorry "+Customer_Name+" you entered an invalid product.(Refer to table for our products) Please Refresh the page to reload and place a new order.");

            }
     var SumOrderTotal = Total_Cost + SumOrderTotal;
     var user_answer=confirm("Would you like to continue purchasing products?");  

    }
    while(user_answer==true);

                document.write("Thank you for placing an order with us, " +Customer_Name+". <br/>");
                document.write("Your total order cost is $"+ SumOrderTotal+ ". <br/>");
```

`

Comment: Please try the answer below and give feedback

Answer (score 2):

move `SumOrderTotal` outside of **do...while**.

Like so:

```
  var SumOrderTotal=0;
  do {      
    Product = prompt("...");
    Quantity = prompt("...");
    var Total_Cost;
  } while (...) {
  ...
  }
```

Because you are initializing to 0 each time you start the cycle(do..while).

Comment: +1 for quick and correct reply  @Floradu88 Format the code... hope you wont mind